# Nginx + Rails, Default url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, nginx, routes, default

I supposedly have my default url set as

> example.com/asd/  ---> my root_path

and everything loads correctly. However, everytime I click a

> '<%= link_to 'something', something_path %>'

I'm directed to

> example.com/something ---> without the /asd.

Is this a problem with my nginx configurations or rails configuration? What should I do to solve it?

> **--Extra-- If I enter to example.com/asd/something, everything loads fine too.**

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

> user www-data;
>
> worker_processes auto;
>
> pid /run/nginx.pid;
>
> events {
>           worker_connections 768; 
>   }
>
> http {
>
> ```
>     sendfile on;
>     tcp_nopush on;
>     tcp_nodelay on;
>     keepalive_timeout 65;
>     types_hash_max_size 2048;
>     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>     default_type application/octet-stream;
>     fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
>     fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
>     fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
>     fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
>     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
>     client_max_body_size 250M;
>     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
>     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
>     error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
>     gzip on;
>     gzip_disable "msie6";
>     gzip_vary on;
>     gzip_proxied any;
>     gzip_comp_level 6;
>     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
>     gzip_http_version 1.1;
>     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json >application/javascripttext/xml application/xml application/xml+rss >text/javascript;
>     include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
>     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>     include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
> ```
>
> }

/etc/nginx/passenger.conf

> passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
>
> passenger_ruby /home/rubyuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby;

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

> server {
>
> ```
>     listen 80 ;
>     listen 443 ssl;
>     server_name example.com;
>     root /home/user/app/current/public;
>     passenger_enabled on;
>     passenger_app_env production;
> ```
>
> }

production.rb

> Rails.application.configure do
>
> ```
>     config.cache_classes = true
>     config.eager_load = true
>     config.consider_all_requests_local= false
>     config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
>     config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true
>     config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
>     config.assets.js_compressor= :uglifier
>     config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
>     config.assets.compile = true
>     config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
>     config.assets.digest = true
>     config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX
>     config.log_level = :debug
>     config.relative_url_root = "/asd"
>     config.action_controller.asset_host = 'example.com'
>     config.i18n.fallbacks = true
>     config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
>     config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
>     config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
>     config.force_ssl = false
>     Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'example.com/asd'
> ```
>
> end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with Rails not with Nginx.
Maybe you're missing a configuration that is not appending the "/asd" (It's been a long time since I used RoR so I don't remember exactly)

A quick fix could be to change **_PATH** for **_URL** *(for example **about_path** would change to **about_url**)* and adding this to the ApplicationsController

```
def default_url_options
   if Rails.env.production?
     {:host => "www.prettyPage.com/asd"}
   else  
     {}
  end
end
```

**_PATH** returns the relative path meanwhile **_URL** returns the absolute path.

For example for "www.page.com/prettyPics" the **_PATH** would be "/prettyPics" and the whole url would be the **_URL**.
This could help a little bit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (Part 2.3)